# Entity Framework - Adding row many to many table without having to load navigational properties

Tags: c#, many-to-many, entity-framework-core

My data model is very simple currently. You have users, and you have restaurants. In between is a many to many relationship called 'Reviews'.

When I want to add a review to the database, I have to retrieve a user object and a restaurant object before I can save the review object. This is done with the following code:

```
// The 'review' object is the object coming as parameter.
var restaurant = await _context.Restaurants.FindAsync(review.RestaurantId);
var user = await _context.Users.FindAsync(review.UserId);

var newReview = _context.Reviews.Add(new DataService.Entities.Review
{
    // setting other values
    Restaurant = restaurant,
    User = user
}).Entity;

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

My `Review` class looks like this:

```
public class Review
{
    // Other properties...
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; }
}
```

And both my user and restaurant class contain lists of reviews.

I'm pretty sure there is a better way to do this, since I don't want to load both objects just to set as navigational properties. I just don't know how to.

I'm using .Net core 2.0 and Entity Framework Core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Review
{
    [Key]
    public int ReviewId { get; set; }

    // Other properties...
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId{get; set;}
    public User User { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Restaurant ")]
    public int RestaurantId {get; set;}
    public Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; }
}
```

That way, you can just set the UserId, and RestaurantId, and you don't have to load the User or Restaurant themselves

Comment: This would most definitely work, but I wanted to know if it's also possible using the fluent api?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the entity class `Review` contains only reference navigation properties with no explicit FK properties.

Still it's possible to do what you are asking because EF Core allows you to get/set [Shadow Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties) representing the FKs (although in a bit unusual way).

In your sample case it would be something like this:

```
var entry = _context.Reviews.Add(new DataService.Entities.Review
{
    // setting other values
});
entry.Property("UserId").CurrentValue = review.UserId;
entry.Property("RestaurantId").CurrentValue = review.RestaurantId;

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```